# Do Server work while i dont connect? If yes how can i do?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, server, gunicorn

I deployed my django app in ubuntu server. I want to give to API for mobile application. So i followed some source and i deployed. For I want to deploye django, I use gunicorn and ngnix.

Server is working with this command:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp.wsgi`

I can give API with this way. Everything is okey.

But when i close cmd which connected to server, server stop. Can server work while i dont connect by my computer? Must not close cmd and my computer? Or can i do other way?

Comment: This is very much standard practice, because obviously not every server has someone's computer SSH'ed into it at all times. What you want is some way to start the server via your SSH connection, and then have it keep running when you leave. A "service" is the common way to do this (set to start on boot, restart on process crash, etc.). There are plenty of tutorials online on setting up services and web-servers like this.

Comment: Can you help me more than please? I want to do that in python django server. When i connect server and run, server is working great. But i close cmd wihich connect to server and server is giving this error: 504 Gateway Time-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! We just need to add "--daemon" in our code. For example:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp.wsgi --daemon
```